# using a semi-transparent png file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image, png, alpha-transparency

I'm trying to paste a png image with a transparency gradient over another image.  Problem: the semi-transparent image doesn't show up at all.  I have the image embedded as a resource in my project, and I suspect the problem is that VB is importing that image as a bitmap (found the following in resources.designer.vb):

```
    Friend ReadOnly Property alphamask() As System.Drawing.Bitmap
        Get
            Dim obj As Object = ResourceManager.GetObject("alphamask", resourceCulture)
            Return CType(obj, System.Drawing.Bitmap)
        End Get
    End Property
```

But so far, I haven't been able to find a workaround for this.  The image, when drawn with

```
        G.DrawImage(My.Resources.alphamask, destRect)
```

in the form_paint event, doesn't show up at all.  By the way, this problem is unique with this one, semi-transparent image.  All the other images I'm using, in exactly the same way, work perfectly.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Just for the record: "all the other images" that work do *not* use transparency at all, or possibly only 1-bit transparency?

Comment: Right.  Some of them do use 1-bit transparency (which works), but none use a full alpha channel.